# SQL query to group by one column (with potential duplicates) and also order by time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, group-by

I have a table for cookie production, where each cookie gets assigned a box number and a time coming out of the oven (cookies come out of the oven one at a time).  A user examines the cookies after exiting the oven and assigns a box number to each.  (Box number is simply incremented throughout the day; only 1 kind of cookie per box.)  I would like to get a list of today's box numbers, sorted by time.  However, at the start of each day, the last box of the previous day may not have been completely filled, so the day may start off with *e.g.* box 56, instead of box 1.  I don't want the first few cookies of the day in box 56 to get mis-associated with the cookies from a potential box 56 later in the day.  So far I have

```
SELECT BoxNo, MAX(CookieType) AS CookieType
FROM Cookies
WHERE TimeOutOfOven >= CONVERT(date, GETDATE())
GROUP BY BoxNo
ORDER BY MIN(TimeOutOfOven)
```

but of course that does not deal with the same box number at discrete times problem.

Comment: At a minimum, I think you are asking for `GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(TimeOutOfOven, '%Y%m%d'), BoxNo`

Comment: Some sample data would help

Comment: Is this an assignment? Or are you able to modify process? Perhaps you can assign a lot number based on when the first cookie was assigned to the box? You could group by `BoxNo` and `CookieType` and hope that the same box number from the one day to the next wouldn't be the same type of cookie.

Comment: @wallyk this is MS SQL Server, not MySQL.

Comment: Whatever.  There are direct substitutions for one vs. the other.

Comment: To the downvoter - if you could provide suggestions on how to improve the question, that would be appreciated.

Comment: @wallyk I checked out MySQL's ``DATE_FORMAT`` and that won't work - there may be 2 discrete instances of the same box number on the same date - but at different times, separated by other box numbers. *e.g.* box 44 at 8am and then repeated at 4pm - but those should be shown as different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT BoxNo, CookieType, TimeOutOfOven
     , LAG(BoxNo, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY TimeOutOfOven) AS PriorBox
 FROM cookie 
WHERE PriorBox <> BoxNo 
  and TimeOutOfOven >= CONVERT(date, GETDATE())

WITH CookiePlus
AS
(
  SELECT * 
       , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TimeOutOfOven) rn
    FROM Cookie
   WHERE TimeOutOfOven >= CONVERT(date, GETDATE())
) 
select cp1.* 
  from CookiePlus cp1 
  left join CookiePlus cp2 
    on cp2.rn = cp1.rn + 1 
 where cp2.boxID <> cp1.boxID 
    or cp2.rn is null
```

Comment: Sorry, should have specified this is SQL Server 2008 - LEAD() is not supported there.

Comment: Yes you should have.    You can do it with row_number and a join.   Look up lag in 2008.

Comment: I am getting the error "The Parallel Data Warehouse (PDW) features are not enabled." when executing - investigating.

Comment: Looks like ``OVER ... ORDER BY`` is not supported in 2008. :(

Comment: Getting that info from http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47116/in-microsoft-sql-server-2008-syntax-generates-the-error-the-parallel-data-ware - I guess it's a bug?

Comment: Looks like you provided lots of help, so I upvoted you.  If Conrad is up to it, he can probably rework your example into a workable solution.

Comment: If I only use the code starting with ``WITH CookiePlus...`` then I do get the desired results. However, it is very compute intensive - the query takes 30+ seconds to execute, which is too long. I will need to optimize.

Comment: So I answered the original question and the revised question of 2008.  It works.  But it is not an answer because it takes too long to run?

Comment: Got pulled off this for a while, but came back and did some experimenting. If I add a ``TimeOutOfOven >= CONVERT(date, GETDATE()) AND`` to the final ``WHERE`` clause (with appropriate parentheses of course), then that reduces processing time drastically. Thanks for the work here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that it takes several hours for all the cookies to come out. Perhaps this general idea will work out.

If the total number of boxes is roughly consistent and the amount of time to fill a box is about the same then you should be able to split the day into three parts: big numbers is the morning, big numbers in the afternoon, all the rest. Tweak the numbers as appropriate.

```
SELECT BoxNo, MAX(CookieType) AS CookieType
FROM Cookies
WHERE TimeOutOfOven >= CONVERT(date, GETDATE())
GROUP BY
    BoxNo,
    CASE
        WHEN BoxNo > 30 AND HOUR(TimeOutOfOven) <  12 THEN 1
        WHEN BoxNo > 30 AND HOUR(TimeOutOfOven) >= 12 THEN 3
        ELSE 2
    END
```

Comment: Pretty sure 56 was just an example

Comment: @Conrad And I posted a solution.  Did you test it?

Comment: @Conrad I've tweaked my post in case you hadn't noticed.

Comment: Yes, thanks; I saw that. Unfortunately, I still can't assume any sort of number threshold - only that ``BoxNo`` values will be grouped by time, and if they are separated by other values, they should have discrete rows returned.

Comment: Ok, well it's still doable without analytic functions. I went ahead and created a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

SplitFlag means this: Is there a lower numbered box that came later in the day? If so then group that box separately.

In more detail, the inner query says: find the lowest box number for all the cookies (not in the same box) that were produced after this one. Since the box numbers are a monotonic sequence (always increasing in value), if there's one later in the day and also lower than the current box number, then the numbers must have reset and the current one is a holdover from the previous day. Gaps in the numbering won't matter.

```
select BoxNo, max(CookieType) as CookieType, SplitFlag
from (
    select
        BoxNo, CookieType,
        case when (
            select min(BoxNo)
            from Cookes as c2
            where c2.TimeOutOfOven > c.TimeOutofOven and c2.BoxNo <> c.BoxNo
        ) < BoxNo then 1 else 0 end as SplitFlag
    from Cookies as c
    where TimeOutOfOven >= convert(date, getdate())
) as T
group by BoxNo, SplitFlag
order by SplitFlag desc, BoxNo
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/20637/1

Comment: I haven't had time to fully debug, but this does not work. I think it is because in my case a box number might occasionally get skipped during production, and if that would have been a duplicate, then it gets put "in order" instead of at the beginning of the day. Way too many corner cases I need to account for!